# How to fix text input form in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I have a basic email contact form that I got from online and I'm trying to send a sample email but some reason I can not enter any text in my input filed. Any suggestion or idea what it might be?

I can enter a text when ever I delete my _formKey but I can not send the email successfully anymore.

Any suggestion or help will be really appreciated.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;



class EmailForm extends StatelessWidget {
  EmailForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final messageController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xfff5f5fd),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 450,
          width: 400,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 40,
            vertical: 20,
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 40,
            vertical: 20,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    offset: const Offset(0, 5),
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    color: Colors.grey[300]!)
              ]),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                const Text('Contact Us',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return '*Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
                  validator: (email) {
                    if (email == null || email.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Required*';
                    } else if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid Email';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: messageController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Message'),
                  maxLines: 5,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return '*Required';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 45,
                  width: 110,
                  child: TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff151534),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40))),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        final response = await sendEmail(
                            nameController.value.text,
                            emailController.value.text,
                            messageController.value.text);
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          response == 200
                              ? const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('Message Sent!'),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.green)
                              : const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('Failed to send message!'),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                        );
                        nameController.clear();
                        emailController.clear();
                        messageController.clear();
                      }
                    },
                    child: const Text('Send', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future sendEmail(String name, String email, String message) async {
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send');
  final response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: json.encode({
        'service_id': '',
        'template_id': '',
        'user_id': '',
        'template_params': {
          'from_name': name,
          'from_email': email,
          'message': message
        }
      }));
  return response.statusCode;
}
```

Comment: Try to use Stateful widget instead of stateless. It might be.

Comment: Ok, thanks bro. Quick question, do you know why I'm getting Failed to send message even thought I pass the correct EmailJS ServiceID, USERID, and TemplateID?

Comment: Put the error logs.

Comment: I'm not sure how to print the error log but basically I'm getting "Failed to send message" in the snackbar. It seem like I'm not getting status 200 based on the code above. Could you pls test it for me in your local pls?

Comment: In case you are following this article, https://blog.devgenius.io/send-emails-without-backend-in-flutter-48d0c506ab4c , try to see if email is setup correctly.

Comment: Put the line -> print(response), Above the ->return response.statusCode; To logs the error.

Comment: Kindly correct the syntax of the data you are sending as it is showing 400 status code so it is bad request referring to the invalid syntax.

Comment: nameController.text I think you should use text controller like this, remove value from controller

Comment: @Maqsood Hi, not sure what you mean, could you pls explain how to do in more details pls?

Comment: @Rahul Hi , I have followed exactly and use two different Gmail but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a Form Widget, you don't necessarily need to use controllers you can used the onchange function in your TextFormField Widget.

Instead of defining TextEditingControllers like this:

```
final nameController = TextEditingController();
final emailController = TextEditingController();
```

Do this instead:

```
var name = '';
var email = '';
```

Instead of

```
TextFormField(
  controller: nameController,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return '*Required';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
```

Do this:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name'),
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == '') {
      return '*Required';
    }
    return null;
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    name = value; //If it gives some null check error just add an exclamation like this - name = value!;
  }
),
```

Now you just have to pass these variables in your request just like you use any normal variables. Instead of using nameController.text, just name (variable created in the beginning) is enough. This should make the form work perfectly.

If you are not getting 200 status then the problem could also be the difference between the data you're sending and the data that is expected to receive on the server.

To figure out the root cause, I would recommend you to add Print Statements everywhere to see which functions are running properly and which are not.

Printing the error statements coming from the server might help in understanding the root problem. So try this before returning statusCode

```
print(response.body); //Add this line for the output from the server
return response.statusCode;
```

And let me know what reply you get in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future sendEmail(String name, String email, String message) async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send%27);
    const serviceId = 'Enter your service Id';
    const templateId = 'Enter your template Id';
    const userId = 'Enter your User Id';
    final response = await http.post(url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},//This line makes sure it works for all platforms.
        body: json.encode({
          'service_id': serviceId,
          'template_id': templateId,
          'user_id': userId,
          'template_params': {
            'from_name': name,
            'from_email': email,
            'message': message
          }
        })
    );
    print (response.body);
    return response.statusCode;

  }
```

You will get Service Id, template Id and User Id from the account that you have created on MailJS.